# Spring Cloud Stream: How to specify single message handler for a set of bindings?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

**Spring Cloud Stream version 1.3.3**

I'm curious about how to attach a single message handler for a set of bindings?
For each binding, I have pretty the same logic:

```
...
    @StreamListener("topic_1")
    void handleCouponCollectedMessage(FirstEventType event) {
        eventsSet.add(event);
    }

    @StreamListener("topic_2")
    void handleProfileUpdateMessage(SecondEventType event) {
        eventsSet.add(event);
    }
...
```

In my project, I'll have much more of such handlers.
So what I'm trying to do is to move bindings-related set up to application.propetions:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic_1.destination=topic_1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic_1.content-type=${TOPIC_ONE_CONTENT_TYPE}
```

The only problem with this approach is that I need to assign somehow (within properties or some general method) a single handler with common logic `eventsSet.add(event)` to each aforementioned binding.

Does `Cloud Stream` support such feature and if yes - maybe someone can share the example?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are few things you can do. First is you can specify multiple destination names per binding (delimited by coma), essentially bridging multiple destinations to a single consumer (e.g., StreamListener).

```
 spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic_1.destination=topic_1, topic_2. . . .
```

You can also go the Spring Integration `bridge` route

Comment: Also, I just noticed, you are using version 1.3.3. Please upgrade since 1.3.x is about to EOL (few more month). We are in 2.1.0 currently. So many new features and enhancements.

Comment: I think I can't use multiple destinations per one binding because in this case, I'll not be able to set unique content type (since I use deserialization in POJO). Also, I'm not able to simply update the dependency because I have much more spring-stuff there.